# Logistic Regression Accuracy rate in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm doing a project in predicting default risk for SBA loans using R. My data has 187,986 positives and only 17796 negatives (9.46%). Clearly this is an imbalanced dataset. That's why when I run accuracy rate checking for my model using probability cutoff value=0.5, the accuracy result is way too low as below,

```
> mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF<-ifelse(mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF=="PIF",1,0)
> pred<-predict(final,newdata=mytestset,type="response")
> y_pred_num<-ifelse(pred>0.5,1,0)
> mean(y_pred_num==mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF)

Result:
[1] 0.009682553
```

When I change the cutoff value to 0.998 and up, the result is way much impressive

> y_pred_num<-ifelse(pred>0.9998,1,0)
>   mean(y_pred_num==mytestset$LoanStatus_PIF)

Result: 
    [1] 0.9997752

Question:
1. Will my model be rejected because I manually choose the cut-off value?
2. Does 0.999 make sense for a cutoff value? As common cut-off value is usually 0.5.

Thanks !

Comment: this is not really a programming question and you might get a better response on stat exchange

Comment: You seem to be asking questions about statistics rather than programming. (It doesn't much seem to matter that you chose R to do your analysis.) If you have questions about the interpretation of statistical models, you should instead ask your questions at [stats.se]. That's the right place for such a discussion.

Comment: Thanks all. Will do !